# perl system call doesn't call ksh script

Tags: perl, system, ksh

I am trying to call a ksh script from my PERL script but am unable to do so.

Here's my command

```
$cmdString = “/path to script/lookupCal.ksh --service 2 -i /auto/dataprod/MSUkeyDates -f /auto/dataprod/HoursOfOpData --timezone America/New_York”
system($cmdString)
```

All I am doing is sending an input file of Msymbolukeys to get an output file with their hours of operation (which will be in HoursOfOpData after the ksh script runs) which I read later in my PERL code.

When I run this from the command line, it works as expected but the call from my PERL script doesn't seem to call the ksh script.

I tried adding some debug statements

```
if(system($cmdTmpstr) != 0)
{
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
}
```

This is the output I get from the logs

```
**child died with signal 11, without coredump**
```

Any tips to fix this?

Comment: You should arguably be at least capturing and checking the status of the command (for zero/non-zero) in the ordinary course of events.  When it is run from the `system()` command, the standard input of the command will be the standard input of Perl, and the standard output of the command will the standard output of Perl.  What I/O redirections are you using on the Perl script?  Does your `lookupCal.ksh` script behave correctly when run with input from `/dev/null` or output sent to `/dev/null`, for example?  Signal 11 is normally SIGSEGV, segmentation violation; that's a problem in the script.

Comment: `$cmdString = “...“;`? What is with the funky double quote character in the OP? Is that `chr(226)`? Is that part of your source code?

Comment: It's just quotes - just think the format changed when I pasted here

Comment: lookupCal.ksh did behave correctly when I ran it with input from /dev/null (< /dev/null) or output sent to /dev/null ( >/dev/null). I just run the PERL script with a bunch of input parameters and finally it writes to the DB  (no input/output redirectons)

Comment: 11 is SIGSEGV. The child died cause it did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
my @cmd = (
    "/path to script/lookupCal.ksh",
    "--service", 2,
    "-i", "/auto/dataprod/MSUkeyDates",
    "-f", "/auto/dataprod/HoursOfOpData",
    "--timezone", "America/New_York"
);
system @cmd;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still does'nt work (exact same functionality)

Comment: Is there anything special I need to consider when running a ksh script from PERL? I read some where else to add ksh -c but that didn't fix the problem either